# How do you overlap text in C terminal

Tags: c, terminal

One of the training exercises in my C programming book goes like following: (translated from swedish)

> If you use a writing/typing terminal you kan sometimes, just like a normal typewriter, underline a word by stepping back on the line and writing _ under the word. Write a program that writes the string in the variable `s` underlined.

my attempt looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char *s;
  printf("input: ");
  scanf("%ms", &s);
  for (int i=0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    printf("%c\b_", s[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

This does not work i expect terminal output to be:

```
$> gcc -Wall -std=c99 file.c  
$> ./file.c  
input: test  
test //underlined
$>
```

but instead i get:

```
$> gcc -Wall -std=c99 file.c  
$> ./file.c  
input: test  
____  
$>
```

does anyone know how to do that or is the book wrong?

Comment: Read about [ANSI escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)s.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The "backspace" escape character '\b' in C, unexpected behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792812/the-backspace-escape-character-b-in-c-unexpected-behavior)

Comment: Read also http://utf8everywhere.org/

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26423857/390913

Comment: If I'm interpreting correctly, you want to literally overlay two characters - so have the single terminal cell display both an alphabetical character and an underline, to create the impression of an underlined character. Afaik, on most **modern** terminals, this is impossible (maybe possible with some terminal-specific hackiness). While `\b` is non-destructive, printing a new character is treated as destructive. You can however print a unicode character with an underline, but you'll need a terminal that supports printing unicode.

Comment: It also works if you pipe it through `less` (because traditional pagers have to be able to display traditional man pages via nroff, which traditionally used overstriking because it was meant to be used on teletypes!)

Comment: just do `printf("\033[XD");`

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a way to allow the literal rendering of one character over another, sadly (I didn't think this was possible with modern terminals, but I'm happy to be proven wrong as [Wumpus Q. Wumbley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46180487/how-do-you-overlap-text-in-c-terminal/46180967#comment79323900_46180487) has made the point that piping through `less` allows for this. I've not had time to look at how/why it works within `less` though).

I'd like to propose a workaround - there is a way to enable underscoring a little more directly using the ANSI code `\033[4m`.

Modifying your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char *s;

  printf("input: ");
  scanf("%ms", &s);
  printf("\033[4m"); // Enable underlining
  printf("%s", s); // Print your string
  printf("\033[0m"); // Reset text attributes (disable underlining)
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

You can find the other ANSI graphic settings in the SGR table in the CSI Codes section on wikipedia, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_codes).

The `\033` specifies it's a terminal escape code, the combination of `\e` with `[` specifies it's a terminal control signal, then the `<number>m` specifies we're doing an "SGR", "Select Graphic Rendition" command, and the number `4` as a parameter corresponds to an effect "Underline: Single". The `0` corresponds to a reset.

I welcome any corrections though, as I don't know much about the ANSI code format.

---

I've just skimmed through the `less` source, and I suspect it's converting sequences like `_\ba` into UTF underlined characters - but I haven't quite got to the bottom of it yet.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is no provision in the Standard for `\e` being a valid character constant; this must be implementation dependent. It does appear to work in gcc for me, but a compiler warning is generated: "warning: non-ISO-standard escape sequence, '\e'". The usual escape sequence is `\x1b` or `\033`, which are ASCII hex and octal values for the ESC character, respectively.

Comment: @DavidBowling Thank you for the correction - I've edited the answer.