# Escape character doesn't work

Tags: c

I want to move the cursor to the x,y position so i use:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int x = 10, y = 10   
    printf("\e[%d;%df",y,x);
    printf("HelloWorld");

}
```

but it's output is:

```
[10;10fHelloWorld
```

I try to change from \e to %c, 0x1B as an example file from my friend but it still not work. It only work in my friend file. What should I do to make it work? or Should I use windows.h instead?

Comment: To go to X, Y position i think `printf("\033[%d;%dH", (x), (y))` should work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to position the input text cursor in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26423537/how-to-position-the-input-text-cursor-in-c)

Comment: It still not work. it's output still be the same(change from f->H)

Comment: For me, it's working! What OS are you using? I am using Cygwin on windows.

Comment: I use Windows 10

Comment: It **should** work on most terminals (given you encode the escape correctly, e.g. `\x1b` or `\033`). But just don't do it, escape-sequences aren't perfectly portable. Use `curses` instead.

Comment: Windows cmd.exe does not implement this kind of terminal emulation

Comment: @Ctx it **does** in windows 10, but the support is turned off by default when a new process launches for backwards compatibility.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Hm, I have other information, can you provide a reference?

Comment: @Ctx here's [the official one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences). Note that `cmd.exe` still disables `ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING` before launching a console application. BTW, `cmd.exe` is only the shell, it indeed doesn't implement these sequences, the console window does.

Comment: @FelixPalmen ic, interesting, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\e` in your code is wrong, but when you repace it by the ASCII code of an escape character and also change `f` to `H` to make it the correct sequence for cursor positioning, your code will work on all terminals that implement ANSI escape sequences. This includes *many* terminals on Linux and other *nix-like systems.

The windows console also supports ANSI escape sequences starting from Windows 10, but this support is disabled by `cmd.exe` by default for backwards compatibility, so to make this code work on Windows 10, you have to explicitly enable this mode:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

// this line is only for older versions of windows headers (pre Win 10):
#define ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING 0x0004

int main(void)
{
    // enable ANSI sequences for windows 10:
    HANDLE console = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    DWORD consoleMode;
    GetConsoleMode(console, &consoleMode);
    consoleMode |= ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING;
    SetConsoleMode(console, consoleMode);

    int x = 10, y = 10;
    printf("\x1b[%d;%dH", y, x);
    printf("HelloWorld");
}
```

---

But that all said, you should really consider using `curses` instead. There are two widespread implementations of the curses library, `ncurses` and `pdcurses`. Both work on a wide variety of systems. My personal recommendation would be `ncurses` for *nix systems and `pdcurses` for windows. If you just `#include <curses.h>` in your code, you can link to both libraries as you want. What you get is full control of your terminal/console output without relying on possibly non-portable escape sequences (it will work on earlier versions than Windows 10 as well).

For learning how to use `curses`, consider the [NCURSES Programming HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/).

Comment: @ArySilna I had the **wrong** flag shown in this example code first, please note the edit :)

Comment: You should also use ```ENABLE_PROCESSED_OUTPUT```