# In C we use \n for the next line. Is there any way to go to previous line?

Tags: c, terminal, output

In C we use `printf("\n");` for the next line. Is there any way to print again from the end of the previous line?

Comment: Some terminals likely have a way to move the cursor up by sending a special code, or calling some other function.  But that depends on your terminal software (or hardware); it's outside the scope of the C language itself.

Comment: What about C++ or other languages?

Comment: Control-K might move up a line.  Remember, in `vim`, you use `l` to go right (so intuitive!) `h` to go left, `j` to go down, `k` to go up – and the control-codes corresponding to those move right, left, down, up.  OTOH, control-K may not work — it depends on the terminal (or terminal emulation) that you're using.  If the cursors is at the start of a line, backspace, control-H, `\b` might move to the end of the previous line; again, it might not.

Comment: It's independent of programming language; it depends on the terminal (terminal emulator) characteristics.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26423537/how-to-position-the-input-text-cursor-in-c

Comment: There are xterm / vt100 control sequences for doing this. When you run CLI stuff that shows something like a progress bar on the terminal, it's writing content like this.

Comment: @seand usually \r is enough for the progress bars

Comment: [man 4 console_codes](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html). (The command should work on Debian / Ubuntu based systems, at least.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use gotoxy() function to move your cursor to a specific point.like this
It will get you to that specific point where you wanna be
if you want some other method that hold on.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main()
{
   int x, y;

   x = 10;
   y = 10;

   gotoxy(x, y);

   printf("C program to change cursor position.");

   getch();
   return 0;
}
```

other thing you can do is to keep printing the statement..it will show it as the new line being started from the end of previous line.

Comment: This isn't standard C though, but a very old MS DOS library which went obsolete some 20 years ago. What makes you think the OP (or anyone else) is still programming in MS DOS?