# how to print with a while also using a scanf statement

Tags: c

I have an odd situation ive made a login system that has many printf and color statements

```
______________________________________________________________
example        border_red(); printf (" $$   ");  
_____________________________________________________________
```

I have multiple printf statements in the menu and in the middle of my code I have a scanf statment to scan the username.  The menu gets cut off halfway through making just the top part of the menu appear.

WHAT THE MENU IS SUPPOST TO LOOK LIKE

```
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
$            username:type here               $
$                                             $
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
```

WHAT THE MENU LOOKS LIKE

```
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
$            username: type here
```

i need the entire menu to show when you type in your username

QUESTION: How would i go about printing letters after a scanf statement

```
char username[50];
printf("#############################");
pritnf("#       username:");
scanf(log, & username);
printf(#                            #');
printf("#############################");
```

how would i go about not having the scanf statement cut off my menu

Sorry if this is a simple question I may have googled it wrong but ive been at this for 1 hour now and this is the only thing I can turn to.

Comment: use proper tagging to your question

Comment: The menu waits for the scanf before printing anything else.

Comment: You need OS-specific ways to handle it, because C++ has no notion of "console".

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26423537/1606345

Comment: @DavidRanieri thank you the program works now

Answer (score 0):

Both `scanf` and `printf` assume line-oriented input and output (think of a hardcopy terminal or teletype).  They're just not designed to print a border, then scan from a location within that border<sup>1</sup>.

If you want to set up borders or place input fields in arbitrary places on screen, you'll have to look beyond the standard C library and use a third-party tool like [ncurses](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/).

---

1. There are tricks you can use - you can send ANSI terminal escape sequences to place the cursor at arbitrary locations on the screen, but it's ugly and a lot of work.  You're better off using a library like ncurses.